# Using Date functions to pull records from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm truly stumped on something - I have a table in my database with a column called 'today' that has Date and Time records.  The column has entries that look like this:

```
October 25, 2014, 4:58 am
October 25, 2014, 4:36 am
```

I'm having trouble pulling the rows by date; I think the time stamp is messing with the MySQL query.  And I need an SQL query to pull any records where the variable $today matches the date information in the column 'today'.  This doesn't work:

```
$today = date("F j, Y"); // looks like this: October 25, 2014

$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM records WHERE today = $today"); // 'today' represents the column in the table

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo var_dump($row);
    }
```

I just get an empty result, I think due to the time stamp.  Can someone advise on a better MySQL query that will only grab the rows where $today matches the date in the 'today' column?

Comment: Date and time are stored as `varchar` in database?

Comment: Correct, varchar(30)

Comment: [You have to use the proper data type `DATETIME` if you want to take full advantage of what MySQL or any other database can offer you not only to date and time but any other fields. `VARCHAR` is not the solution to all your columns.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html)

Comment: You can try it with this: "SELECT * FROM records WHERE today LIKE '$today%'" but that's not a nice solution

Comment: *"This doesn't work:"* - is not a very descriptive reason. You're probably not checking for errors, which will/should since you're querying a string, and not an integer. Strings need encapsulating quotes. Add `or die(mysqli_error($link))` to `mysqli_query()` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I updated the column to datetime so they look like this now: 2014-10-25 09:24:10  -- what would be the proper way to execute the syntax now that the datetime is fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although storing the date and time as string in `varchar` is not really a good idea, you could still alter your query to match `string` containing the current date with a `LIKE` statement:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM records WHERE today LIKE '$today%'");
```

That is just to get your current setup working as a temporary fix but i highly suggest you take a look at `datetime` and `timestamp` or similar date types if this is a serious project and not just playing around. with programming.

**UPDATE**

With a `datetime` you could get the dates which are the same as today with:

```
SELECT * FROM `records` WHERE `today` = CURDATE();
```

with a `timestamp` you would need to pass it as `date` so your query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM `records` WHERE date(`today`) = CURDATE();
```

Comment: Thank you!!  So I should store not store the date and time as varchar?  I will take your advise and look closer at datetime and timestamp.  I'm still a bit of a noob.

Comment: Exactly, a good choice would be using a `timestamp` which has a similar format as your current one, yet allows `mysql` to "understand" and use it in a proper format for comparisons, selections etc.

Comment: The date/datetime types allow you to compare dates like numbers, add years, months, dates and so on... Just read online manuals.

Comment: I updated the column to datetime so they look like this now: 2014-10-25 09:24:10 -- what would be the proper way to execute the syntax now that the datetime is fixed?

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the MySQL date functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM records
WHERE today = CURRENT_DATE;
```

If there is a time component on the `today` column, then the best structure is:

```
SELECT *
FROM records
WHERE today >= CURRENT_DATE and today < date_add(CURRENT_DATE, interval 1 day)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that both dates are not equal. Both dates are treated like text values and are not equal. You need to convert the column containing date in your MySQL query as such:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM records WHERE DATE_FORMAT(today, '%F %j, %Y') = $today");
```

Note that you have to change your column to store values of the type of DATE. Or just use queries as proposed in other answers.